# PHP mail from user instead of webmaster

Tags: php, email

I am currently using this php code to send a mail from a form on my website, and it works fine, with one exception : when we receive the email it shows as sent by "webmaster@mydomain.com" instead of the user's email.

This is the php :

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
// Checking For Blank Fields..
if($_POST["vname"]==""||$_POST["vemail"]==""||$_POST["vphone"]==""||$_POST["msg"]==""){
echo "Fill All Fields";
}else{
// Check if the "Sender's Email" input field is filled out
$email=$_POST['vemail'];
// Sanitize E-mail Address
$email=filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
// Validate E-mail Address
$email=filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (!$email){
echo "Invalid Sender's Email";
}
else{
$subject = "Contact site";
$message = "\n\nMessage from: ".$_POST["vname"]."\nPhone: ".$_POST["vphone"]."\nEmail: ".$_POST["email"]."Message:\n\"".$_POST["msg"]."\"";
$headers = 'From:'. $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$headers .= 'Cc:'. $email . "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
// Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
mail("contact@mydomain.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "Email sent !";
}
}
}
```

Comment: what's the value of $email?

Comment: @RafaelShkembi <input name="vemail" placeholder="email adress" type="text" value=""> in the html file

Comment: Go to the link that mark gived to you. The problem is $headers = 'From:'. $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email.. check this line of code

Comment: @RafaelShkembi Adding '$params = "-f ".$email."\r\n";' and 'mail("contact@mydomain.com", $subject, $message, $headers, $params);' doesn't seem to solve the problem :/

Comment: if you echo  $headers what's you get?

Comment: @RafaelShkembi 
From:my_test_email@gmail.com
Cc:my_test_email@gmail.com

Comment: remove $headers and add From:my_test_email@gmail.com . Did anything change?

Comment: @RafaelShkembi works fine, sender is my email adress... But of course I'd like it to be a variable adress. Is the '$headers = 'From:'. $email . "\r\n";' line not appropriate ?

Comment: Yor problem is in the $email variable read all the script and find where is the part that assign the value of sender

Comment: @RafaelShkembi '$email=$_POST['vemail'];'